# Adding quantity in my reactjs ecommerce website basket

Tags: reactjs

I have created my online shoe store website using react. In my cart list I'm trying to increase the quantity of items and along with quantity I'm trying to increase total price too. I tried some ways as of my capabilities but I'm not getting good result.

In the code below I created a state using useState hook then with two buttons. I'm trying to increase and decrease my state. by that state then I'm trying to increase the quantity of my item then trying to multiply the price with that quantity. it works fine if there is one item in the cart. if there are more than 1 item, the button to increase the quantity of one item showing in my cart, it also increase the quantity of other item too. Thus the price also increase.

[image]

```
   <Paper className={classes.total}>
    <h3>Total Items: {itemsInCart.length}</h3>
    <h3>Total Price: ${total}</h3>
  </Paper>

  <Container className={classes.root}>
    <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.container}>
      {itemsInCart.map((shoe) => (
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={shoe.id}>
          <img
            src={shoe.imgurl}
            alt=""
            height="200px"
            className={classes.img}
            onClick={() => {
              navigate(`/products/${shoe.id}`);
            }}
          />

          <Typography variant="body1">{shoe.name}</Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2">Price: ${shoe.price}</Typography>
          <div>
            <span>Quantity</span>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
            {(shoe.qty = count)}

            <button
              onClick={() => {
                shoe.qty > 1 ? setCount(count - 1) : setCount(1);
              }}
               >
              -
            </button>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  </Container>
</>
```

);
};`

Comment: The problem is likely to be in the way you're currently updating your state. Can you put the code that handles to click on the "Add item" (+) button?

Comment: i edited the code kindly review it

Comment: Can you add your state shape. I expect to see an array of objects representing items in a cart. Each item would have a property of 'quantity'. However, the way you have setCount slice of state, it looks like all items share that count.

Comment: yes each of items having a quantity property. what should i use so this count state should only to the specific items whose quantity i want to increase

Comment: A couple of things: *First*, there is a weird piece of code where you change the shoe's quantity setting it to `count` (not sure where this `count` is coming from): `shoe.qty = count`. Remeber that you state should be immutable. *Second*, you still didn't post the code for the "+" button, what is `countIn()` doing? How does it know which cart item needs its quantity changed?

Comment: sorry i was unable to add that since the editor does not accept that code but what `countIn()` doing is to increment the quantity. `setCount(count + 1)`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a parent component that holds your cart state and you map over and return a child component i.e. card.

The problem is that you are giving your card component a slice of state of count. Instead, you should create a updateCartHandler on the parent component and pass it as a prop to the card component.

```
const updateCartHandler = (id, value) => {
   let updatedCart = cart.map(item => item.id === id ? item.quantity += value : item)

   setCart(updatedCart)

}
```

Pass updatedCartHandler as a prop. And when it gets called in the card component, make sure you're passing both, id and value.

```
<div>
            <span>Quantity</span>
            <button onClick={() => props.updateCartHandler(shoe.id, +1)}>+</button>
            {shoe.qty}

            <button
              onClick={() => props.updateCartHandler(shoe.id, -1)}
               >
              -
            </button>
          </div>
```

Comment: Upvoted, although I'm still not sure about the actual scenario that the OP has, this seems very reasonable. I'm still a bit concerned with the `shoe.qty = count` though... @Jawad Khan make sure `shoe` IS NOT coming from component's `state` or `props`.

Comment: @IPValverde thank you! just noticed that as well, updated to just `{shoe.qty}`